# Black tar-like stucky subtance leaking slowly building/leaking from furnace pipe

Tags: furnace

[image]Could someone please tell me what this substance is that is leaking from my furnace pipe?  It seems to be coming from the gasket area (see pictures).  Thank youenter image description here

Comment: What in in a "furnace pipe" ?  Fuel oil ? Fuel gas ? Boiler water ? I once had an oil furnace that had combustion air in a pipe.

Comment: If those two bolts when you place wrenches on them to turn and don't feel tight, you might be able to fix the leak by tightening both bolts more, give each bolt one turn at a time.  If not then will need to replace the gasket.

Comment: What fuel does your furnace use?